# ¿Cómo retorno un valor next() de una funcion para usarlo en otra?

Tags: java

mi problema es que tengo que hacer un ejercicio de ahorcado pero tengo que tener un menú, por lo cual e decidido hacer varias funciones en el primer punto del menú tengo que poner la palabra y en el segundo que me inicie el juego como tal, pero necesito que me recuerde esa palabra para seguir con el proceso que es la "palabra inicial" que es una palabra que poner el jugado, estoy jugando con los arreglos pero no se como se retornaría el valor siendo un arreglo

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ejercicioAhorcado {
    // Variables Globales
    static String palabraInicial;
    static Scanner teclado = new Scanner (System.in);
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean salir=false; 
        System.out.println("BIENVENIDO AL JUEGO AHORCADO");     
        byte opcion = menu();
        switch (opcion) {
                    case 1: 
                        añadirPalabra();
                        break;
                    case 2: 
                        iniciarJuego();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                       salir = true;
                        break;
        
      }        
    }
    
    public static void iniciarJuego(){
        String palabraJuego = "";
            System.out.println("La palabra a buscar tiene la siguiente longitud: ");

            for (int i = 0; i < palabraInicial.length() / 2; i++) { //imprimo _ por cada letra que tenga la palabra
                palabraJuego += "_ ";
 System.out.println(palabraJuego);
    }
    
    public static String añadirPalabra() {
            System.out.println("Jugador 1 introduzca la palabra deseada (sin numeros ni espacios)");
            palabraInicial = teclado.next();
            String palabraAux = palabraInicial;
            palabraInicial = "";

            for (int l = 0; l < palabraAux.length(); l++) {
                palabraInicial += "" + palabraAux.charAt(l) + " ";
            }
            return palabraInicial;
            }
    }
    
    
    
    public static void dibujoIntentos(){
    
    }
    
    public static byte menu() {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("MENU");
        System.out.println("1. Ingresa Palabra");
        System.out.println("2. Jugar");
        System.out.println("3. Salir");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Porfavor seleccione una opcion: ");
        return teclado.nextByte();
    }
    
    public static void dibujoFinal () {
    System.out.println("------\n" +
        "|  |\n" +
        "|  o\n" +
        "| /|\\\n" +
        "| / \\\n" +
        "|\n" +
        "|___");
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No estaba seguro hasta donde darte el ejemplo, así que me he limitado a contestarte la pregunta, o sea, enviar la palabra seleccionada por el usuario al método de iniciar juego y pintarla en pantalla

La forma que lo tengo programado es una entre tantas posibilidades. He corregido algún error que tenías en el código. He transformado la palabra elegida en un arrar tipo char, mucho más sencillo de utilizar a la hora de comparar las letras que vayan introuciendo por teclado.

El dibujo final, también te lo he metido en un array de tipo String, que podrás ir dibujando en pantalla si se va cometiendo errores en las letras

Bueno, te dejo el codigo y comentas si te sirve, si te aclara algo y si puedes continuar a partir de ahí

Si no, ya sabes, preguntas donde vuelvas a tener dudas

```
public class Ahorcado {
    // Variables Globales
    static String palabraInicial;
    static Scanner teclado = new Scanner (System.in);


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //el método main por ahora lo dejamos solo para iniciar el juego
        //declaramos un array de caracteres vacío
        char[] palabra = {};
        //llamamos al método menú y le pasamos el array por parámetro
        metodoMenu(palabra);
    }
    public static void metodoMenu(char[] palabra){
        //declaramos la variable opcion de tipo byte
        byte opcion;
        //evaluamos que el array de caracteres sea distinto de cero
        if (palabra.length != 0){
            //si lo es, imprimimos el texto iniciamos juego
            System.out.println("INICIAMOS JUEGO");
            //asignamos el valor 2 a la variable opcion
            opcion = 2;
        }
        else{
            //si el array de caracteres está vacío, imprimimos la bienvenida
            System.out.println("BIENVENIDO AL JUEGO AHORCADO");  
            //llamamos al método menú y recibimos el resultado de la opción deseada
            opcion = menu(); 
        }    
      
    boolean salir=false; 
    //iniciamos las opciones en función de la opción elegida
    switch (opcion) {
                //si es uno
                case 1: 
                    //llamamos al método añadir palabra y recibimos la palabra como array de caracteres
                    palabra = añadirPalabra();
                    //volvemos a llamar al método menú y le pasamos el array como parámetro
                    metodoMenu(palabra);
                    break;
                //en caso de querer iniciar el juego
                case 2: 
                    //si el array de caracteres tiene alguna letra, aquí por no complicar mucho el código no se evalúa que solo se puedan introducir caracteres, que para elo podrías hacer un método a parte que lo hiciera
                    if (palabra.length != 0){
                        //llamamos al método iniciar juego y le enviamos el array por parámetro
                        iniciarJuego(palabra);
                    }
                    else{
                        //si el array está vacío, damos el aviso por pantalla
                        System.out.println("Para iniciar el juego tiene que añadir una palabra");     
                        //volvemos a llamar al método menú enviando el array vació como parámetro
                        metodoMenu(palabra);
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    //salimos del programa
                    teclado.close();
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;       
        }        
    }

    public static void iniciarJuego(char[] palabra){
        //limpiamos el bufer del teclado
        teclado.nextLine();
        //damos información de la longitud de la palabra
        System.out.println("La palabra a buscar tiene la siguiente longitud: " + palabra.length);
        //hayamos el número de espacios
        int espacios = palabra.length - 2;
        //imprimimos el primer caracter de la palabra (array de caracteres 0)
        System.out.print(palabra[0] + " ");
        //hacemos un bucle para dibujar los espacios
        for (int i = 0; i < espacios; i++) { //imprimo _ por cada letra que tenga la palabra
            System.out.print(" _ ");
        }
        //imprimimos el último caracter de la palabra
        System.out.print(" " + palabra[palabra.length - 1]);
        //imprimimos una línea en blanco
        System.out.println("");

        //a partir de aquí, te tocaría seguir con la resolución del ejercicio
        //la plabra elegida la tienes en el array de caracteres
        //ahora tendrías que empezar a pedir letras por teclado
        //comprobar que estén en la palabra
        //si lo está, localizar su lugar y escribirla
        //si no lo está, llamar al método dibujo final
        //Venga, a por ello, suerte!!!
    }

    public static char[] añadirPalabra() {
        //limpiamos el bufer del teclado
        teclado.nextLine();
            //pedimos la palabra por teclado
            System.out.println("Jugador 1 introduzca la palabra deseada (sin numeros ni espacios)");
            //almacenamos la palabra (Suponiendo que solo se introuzca una palabra, pues no lo evaluamos), en la variable palabraInicial
            palabraInicial = teclado.nextLine();
            //no la uso
            String palabraAux = palabraInicial;
            //palabraInicial = "";

            //declaramos un array de caracteres denominado palabra formado por palabraInicial
            char[] palabra = palabraInicial.toCharArray();
            //retornamos el array de caracteres
            return palabra;
    }

    public static void dibujoIntentos(){

    }

    public static byte menu() {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("MENU");
        System.out.println("1. Ingresa Palabra");
        System.out.println("2. Jugar");
        System.out.println("3. Salir");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Porfavor seleccione una opcion: ");
        return teclado.nextByte();
    }

    public static void dibujoFinal () {
        //declaramos un array de string formado por el dibujo del ahorcado, cada línea es un string distinto del array
        String[] dibujoAhorcado = new String[7];

            dibujoAhorcado[6] = "----\n";
            dibujoAhorcado[5] = "|  |\n";
            dibujoAhorcado[4] = "|  o\n";
            dibujoAhorcado[3] = "| /|\\\n";
            dibujoAhorcado[2] = "| / \\\n";
            dibujoAhorcado[1] = "|\n";
            dibujoAhorcado[0] = "|_______";
    }
}
```